# A cyclic inequality on three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers and denote $M = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - a^2b - b^2c - c^2a$, $N = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2(a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)$.

a) Show that if $M = 0$, then $N \geq 0$.

b) If $M=1$, find the largest possible value of $N$.

c) (sorry, that's what I wanted to say in b)) If $M=1$, find the smallest possible value of $N$ (if there is no such but $N$ is bounded, then determine the infimum)

So the approach given in one of the answers for b) should help for c), I think? I suspect that the minimal/infimum value is 2 but can we show this somehow? The obvious choice $a = b = c$ gets the 2 but fails $M=1$

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M=0$, then 
$$
N = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) \\
= a^2(a-1)^2 + b^2(b-1)^2 + c^2(c-1)^2 \ge 0
$$

If $M=1$ then 
$$
N = a^4 + b^4 + c^4 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 -1) \\
= (a^2-a)^2 +(b^2-b)^2 + (c^2-c)^2 +2 
$$
but this can grow arbitrarily large.

Comment: To finish this, we just need to show, that $a^3+b^3+c^3-a^2b-b^2c-c^2a=1$ can be true for arbitrarily large numbers.  

Let $a=b=T $ than for $c$ we must have:

 $c^3-Tc^2-T^2c+T^3-1=0$

Polynomial $f(c)=c^3-Tc^2-T^2c+T^3-1$ is negative when $c=T$, but postive when $c\rightarrow \infty$ so we will have solution in $(T, \infty)$

Comment: @AO1992 Thanks for completing this. As $T$ also gets arbitrarily large, there will always be a solution to $f(c) = 0$ and at the same time with large $T$, we have that  $N$ will get arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot! Can you similarly find suitable triples for which the infimum is shown to be 2 - I hope that this is true. I have edited the question.

Comment: Desmond: this is clear from  $N = (a^2-a)^2 +(b^2-b)^2 + (c^2-c)^2 +2$, we have $N \ge 2$ as the squares are nonnegative. Now for $a=b=c=1$ we have $N=2$ so this is indeed a (tight) minimum.

Answer (score 0):

1) $M\geq0$ by Rearrangement.

Indeed, $(a^2,b^2,c^2)$ and $(a,b,c)$ they are same ordered.

Thus, $$a^3+b^3+c^3=a^2\cdot a+b^2\cdot b+c^2\cdot c\geq a^2\cdot b+b^2\cdot c+c^2\cdot a.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c$, which gives $$N=3a^4+3a^2-6a^3=3a^2(a-1)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Is there a hint in the fact that rearrangement is spelled "Rearangement" ( Note : I mean why is it capitalized ) ?

Comment: @TheCoolDrop It's inequality.See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/rearrangement-inequality/info